# Collapsible Content Boxes not working

Tags: html, html.dropdownlistfor

I have been searching for a solution including many here on Stackoverflow but am still not able to get it working hence the question.

The aim is to place collapsible content boxes in a simple html page. After looking at several demos I feel the following looks best and quite easy to install (script is already hosted, only have to deal with html): http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_collapsible_sets

I have pasted the following into head:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>`

Omitted meta name and link rel because if they're included, the page's formatting is messed up (some header text becomes bold, buttons are misaligned).

The following was placed at the desired location on the page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Collapsible Sets</h1>
  </div>

...

<div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Insert Footer Text Here</h1>
</div>
    </div>
```

However, the hiding function is not working when I view the page in Firefox; everything is shown. Can someone advise please?

---

Thank you Andy. I've managed to get it somewhat working but found that it messes up my fonts and stuff. Removing this line from head

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
```

fixes it, but renders the collapsible set broken. I don't believe they're expecting people to put their code into a site that doesn't use CSS, and obviously I'm not going to dump mine and use theirs, so how can I make this linked CSS play nice with my existing one?

Also, I am trying to embed a a Jotform code into the set. However, even though I've pasted the code inside (tried embed, iframe, source) nothing shows up in the expanded panel. Help?

Answer (score 0):

I have been learning Jquery Mobile also.

Your header needs the following, just basics so you can get it working :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>my test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Now within your body try the following pasted within the body of pageone:-

```
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<div data-role="collapsibleset">
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h3>
    <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h3>
    <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h3>
    <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h3>
    <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would strongly recommend spending a little time on the Jquery Mobile site http://jquerymobile.com/

The collapsible set widget is directly linked here http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsibleset/

Comment: Anyone? I don't really have much time to get this done.

Comment: So what I posted above did not work, or you did not understand it ? Please you need to acknowledge even if it is wrong for people to be able to further help you. Could you strip your code down to the basic to show us what you have or load a jsfiddle at least ? If you do not try to put out as much as possible you will find very few answers or people inclined to offer advice.

Comment: Hi Andy, due to the strange way this place works (sorry I'm new), I was only able to provide an in-depth reply to your post by editing my original post. I added a long line to separate it from the original question. I apologize for any misunderstanding. I will upload the code to jsfiddle shortly. Thank you for your patience.